# copying elements of an array-list to the other array-list

Tags: java

I have written such a simple code:

- I have written this line in my class's constructor : `List element = new ArrayList();`
- I have a variable named `cost` which its type is  `int`
- one method will return three lists with different objects: `listOne, listTwo, listThree`
- in another method I have written below code which this method will use those lists that are created in the method above.this method will be called three times for three lists above. each call for each list.

  ```
  // begining of the method:
  int cost = 0;

  if(cost==0){
      element = listOne;
      cost = 3;
  }
  if(cost<4){
      element = listtwo;
      cost = 6;
  }
  // end

  System.out.println(element.toString());
  ```

Unfortunately, instead of printing `listTwo` it will print `listThree` (if we have 4 or more lists it will print the last one)!

Is there any problem with if-else condition?

thanks

EDIT: this is my main code but its condition is like the code above:
`auxiliaryList` in the code below is `listOne` or `list Two` or `listThree` respectively.

```
cost = 0;

public void method {


                System.out.println(element.toString());//number one
                if (cost== 0) {


                element = auxiliaryList;
                cost = 3;

                }
                else if( cost<4){

                        element =auxiliaryList;
                         cost = 6;
                }

            }
            return;

        }

}
```

also the line which is declared with `//number one` shows me that before going to the if/else condition ,the element list will be set to the current list in the method.

Comment: I don't see a if-else condition, only two if

Comment: seems like its printing last list only. can you debug the value of cost. One more check could be the lists might be getting empty because of initializing the constructor. else move the initialization  List element = new ArrayList(); outside of constructor

Comment: the value of cost is Ok!! but as I said for Jon Skeet:I have checked that before going in to the if-else condition ,the element list will be set with the current list.I mean for the third list,before going in to the if-else condition,the element list will be set to thirdList!!!

Comment: You say that "This is my main code", but it doesn't even compile, as you posted it! Why don't you post the *real* code? Posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be even better.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any problem with if-else condition.

Yes - the problem is that you're not *using* if/else, you're just using two if statements.

Change the second `if` to use an `else` and it'll be fine:

```
  if (cost == 0) {
      element = listOne;
      cost = 3;
  } else if (cost < 4) {
      element = listtwo;
      cost = 6;
  }
```

The problem was that if `cost` was 0, it would enter the first block, set `cost` to 3, and then go into the *second* block because 3 is less than 4. There was no "else" to stop that happening - the two `if` blocks were entirely independent.

Comment: @user472221: In that case you need to give us a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. I've fixed what's wrong with the small portion of the program which you've shown us, but there could be other things wrong with it in any number of places.

Comment: Ok,also I have checked that before going in to the if-else condition ,the element list will be set with the current list.I mean for the third list,before going in to the if-else condition,the element list will be set to thirdList!!!

Comment: @user472221: That's still not a short but complete program. Please post something we can compile, paste, compile and run with no other changes.

Comment: @user472221: Create a copy of it, and cut down everything that isn't required *just to demonstrate the problem*. In doing so, you're very likely to find the problem yourself.